# Почему не запускается django проект на порте на рабочем сервере gunicorn + nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Не хочет запускаться проект на VPS.
Ошибка:

> 1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.245.120.83, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6112/", host: "mysite.com"

```
upstream app_server_wsgiapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:6112 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/media/;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://app_server_wsgiapp;
    }
    charset off;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/mysite.com/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.error.log notice;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com;
    root $root_path;
    listen XX.XXX.XX.XXX:80;
}
```

/etc/systemd/system/mysite.service

```
[Unit]
Description=mysite daemon
Requires=mysite.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/sokovblogpr
ExecStart=/var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/mysiteenv/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:6112 mysitepr.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/mysite.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=sokovblog socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/mysite.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

systemctl status mysite

```
● mysite.service - mysite daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysite.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-12-07 18:54:42 CET; 16min ago
TriggeredBy: ● mysite.socket
   Main PID: 4360 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1843)
     Memory: 45.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysite.service
```

Если в терминале запускаю, тогда всё работает.

```sh
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:6112 mysitepr.wsgi
```

И если вот это запускаю в терминале, тоже работает ожидаемо - показывает страницу в терминале.

```sh
curl --unix-socket /run/mysite.sock localhost
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы уж определитесь с чем-то одним - или слушайте порт 6112, или слушайте unix-сокет, и перенастройте все конфиги на что-то одно

Comment: @andreymal то есть вы знаете что я делаю не так, но не хотите помочь. Так это сообщество работает?

Comment: Вы настроили nginx на подключение к порту 6112, а mysite.socket настроили на прослушивание unix-сокета. Вполне логично, что они не могут сконтачиться друг с другом, это ж абсолютно разные никак не связанные сокеты

Comment: @andreymal нужно сделать как в этой инструкции? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-i-nastrojka-django-s-postgres-nginx-i-gunicorn/amp/

Comment: Эта инструкция устарела на девять лет (она был устаревшей уже на момент публикации). Нужно в первую очередь понимать, что вы вообще делаете, а не бездумно следовать инструкциям. И судя по вашим действиям и вашим ответы на мои комментарии, я подозреваю, что вам нужно для начала почитать какую-то общую литературу о том, как работают компьютерные сети, чем TCP-порты отличаются от unix-сокетов, как пользоваться systemd и каков принцип действия socket-юнитов

Comment: Ну а если вам неохота разбираться и вы хотите чтобы заработало хоть как-нибудь — наверное, удалите `mysite.socket` за ненадобностью и уберите строчку `Requires=mysite.socket` из service-файла, сделайте `systemctl daemon-reload` и перезапустите `systemctl restart mysite` — тогда, может, начнёт нормально слушаться и работать порт 6112 (если в service-файле нет каких-нибудь других ошибок, этого я не могу знать)

Comment: @andreymal золотой вы человек! Спасибо большое. Конечно нужно разобраться и почитать документацию. Просто сейчас нужно с одного хостинга перекинуть на сервер быстро. Сильно ограничен во времени. Ещё раз спасибо.